# Is it possible to watch a video frame by frame on the iPhone?

Tags: video, iphone, ios

I am wondering if I can review a video I shot frame by frame on the iPhone.
The video was shot on the iPhone.

I have tried the feature that consists in expanding the frames under the video to get better control of the playback but it's not as precise as frame by frame for me.

I know how to do it after the video is exported to QuickTime but it's not what I'm looking for.

I couldn't find any help online.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I'm aware, the only way to do this is with 3rd party apps.

Although I've never personally used [VideoPix](https://appsto.re/au/rtbZx.i)  I am aware of someone who was using it a few years back and was happy with it.

Of course there are probably hundred of apps that can do this, so you should find one you're happy with.

Answer (score 2):

So I found an app which do that, the UI is. It great and adapted to new devices, but it’s work perfect well, At least did the job in my case.

You can click on the next frame and go at your own speed or pause, and even zoom or mirroring.

CMV: Slow Frame-Frame Video Analysis CoachMyVideo by CoachMyVideo.com, inc. https://itunes.apple.com/ie/app/cmv-slow-frame-frame-video-analysis-coachmyvideo/id499915119?mt=8